# Why are stdin and stdout seemingly interchangeable?

Tags: c++, macos, shell, unix, stdout

I understand that stdin and stdout (at least in UNIX parlance) are stream buffers, and that stdout is used to output from a program to the console (or to then be piped by a shell, etc), and that stdin is for standard input to a program..

So why is it, at least on macOS, that they can be used interchangeably (stdout as stdin, and vice versa?

Examples:

1. If you run `cat /dev/stdin` then type something in, and it echoes it back. Running the command as `cat /dev/stdout` does the same thing.
2. Similarly, `echo "Hey There" > /dev/stdout` and `echo "Hey There" > /dev/stdin` both output 'Hey There' back to the terminal.
3. It also works in C++:

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::string echoString;
    std::fstream stdoutFile;
    stdoutFile.open("/dev/stdout");
    stdoutFile << "Hey look! I'm using stdout properly!\nNow You trying using it wrongly: " << std::endl;
    stdoutFile >> echoString;
    stdoutFile << "You Typed: " << echoString << std::endl;
}
```

When prompted, typing a single word, followed by EOF (Ctrl+D) works as expected.

Comment: Note that the fact that `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout` are interchangeable does **not** imply that `stdin` and `stdout` are interchangeable. In particular, if you start a process with `> /dev/stdin` then it will not be possible to read from the process's standard output stream.

Comment: @Brian what do you mean? This seems to work: http://pastebin.com/Su3yuJax

Comment: That's not the same as what I said. `std::fstream` opens in read/write mode by default. If you do `> foo` on the terminal, it will open `foo` in write-only mode and the file descriptor will not be usable for reading.

Comment: @Brian right I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, typically, when a program is invoked from an interactive terminal, with no redirection, both standard input and standard output are connected to the same terminal device, such as `/dev/tty` (the actual device name varies based on the operating system).

The terminal device is a read/write device. Reading from the terminal device reads terminal input. Writing to the terminal device generates output on the terminal.

You still have discrete file descriptors, 0 and 1, but they're connected to the same device.

Think of it as single, bi-directional pipe, that's `dup`ed to both file descriptors 0 and 1.

Linux behaves the same way (you can `echo Foo >/dev/stdin` and see the output):

```
$ ls -al /proc/self/fd/[01]
lrwx------. 1 mrsam mrsam 64 Nov 22 21:34 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------. 1 mrsam mrsam 64 Nov 22 21:34 /proc/self/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/1
```

So, for this process, file descriptors 0 and 1 is connected to the `/dev/pts/1`, the same pseudo-terminal device. Whether you are reading from file descriptor 0 or file descriptor 1, you end up reading from the same underlying `/dev` device, so it makes no difference which actual file descriptor you use.

This is, of course, operating system-dependent. Other POSIX-based operating systems may implement their standard input and output in other ways, where you can't actually write to standard input and read from standard output.

Comment: Nice example with `/proc`

Answer (score 0):

As you said, they're just stream buffers. There is nothing about them that enforces a particular usage pattern - just convention. The stream buffers stdin, stdout, and stderr are all provided as a programming convenience.